# PowerApps | Concat not working if fields place in Gallery Control inside data card which is inside the Form

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, power-platform

If the Input Fields are place on screen without any form and we concat the fields it works
[image]

[image]

```
Set(varStr1,Concat(Gallery1.AllItems,Concatenate(TextInput1.Text,";",TextInput2.Text,"|")))
```

But same thing  if I place them Form --> Data Card --> Gallery-->Input Field Concat does not work

```
//Set(varStr2,Concat(Gallery2.AllItems,Concatenate(TextInput4.Text,";",TextInput5.Text,"|")))
//UpdateContext({varStr4:Concat(Gallery3_1.AllItems,Concatenate(TextInput5_1.Text,";",TextInput4_1.Text,"|"))});
Set(varStr4,Concat(Gallery3_1.AllItems,Concatenate(TextInput4_1.Text,";",TextInput5_1.Text,"|")))
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Gallery inside a Form DataCard then position the Button inside the gallery and it will work. Here the onselect property of the button is

```
Set(varStr1,Concat(Gallery1.AllItems,Concatenate(TextInput1.Text,";",TextInput2.Text,"|")))'.
```